# Função para pegar dias da semana

Tags: javascript, data

Estou fazendo um relógio que também mostra os dias da semana, porém gostaria de conseguir mostrar o valor com o nome por extenso. Eu até consegui fazer isso fazendo um monte de `if`, mas eu queria fazer uma função em vez disso, como faço? Uso o `for`?

```
function carregar(){
    setInterval(() => {
        let data = new Date()
        let diasemana = data.getDay()
        let dia = data.getDate()
        let mes = data.getMonth() + 1 //Coloquei +1 porque o resultado estava sendo o mês anterior
        let ano = data.getFullYear()
        let hora = data.getHours()
        let min = data.getMinutes()
        let seg = data.getSeconds()
        let hou = data.getHours()
        let pe = "AM"
        let dw = ["Domingo", "Segunda-Feira", "Terça-Feira", "Quarta-Feira", "Quinta-Feira", "Sexta-Feira", "Sábado",]
        let mo = Array["Janeiro", "Fevereiro", "Março", "Abril", "Maio", "Junho", "Julho", "Agosto", "Setembro", "Outubro", "Novembro", "Dezembro"]
        let dias = window.document.getElementById('dias')
        let relogio = window.document.getElementById('relogio')

        dias.innerHTML = `${diasemana} ${dia} / ${mes} / ${ano} `
        relogio.innerHTML = `${hora} : ${min} : ${seg} oi`
        
        if(diasemana == 0) {
            diasemana = dw[0]
        } else if(diasemana == 1) {
            diasema = dw[1]
        } else if(diasemana == 2) { 
            diasemana = dw[2]
        } else if(diasemana == 3) {
            diasemana = dw[3]
        } else if(diasemana == 4) {
            diasemana = dw[4]
        } else if(diasemana == 5) {
            diasemana = dw[5]
        } else {
            diasemana = dw[6] }
        
        //AM e PM
        if(hou >= 12){
             pe = "PM";
        } if(hou == 0){
            hou = 12;
        } if(hou > 12){
             hou = hou - 12;
        }
        //Mudando para String os dias da semana

        dias.innerHTML = `${diasemana} ${dia} / ${mes} / ${ano} `
        relogio.innerHTML = `${hora} : ${min} : ${seg} ${pe}`
    }, 1);
}
```

Comment: Você quer que os `ifs` virem uma função ou posso substituilos por um `for`?

Answer (score 6):

Basicamente, nesse `if`:

```
if(diasemana == 0) {
    diasemana = dw[0]
} else if(diasemana == 1) {
    diasemana = dw[1]
    etc...
```

Você está fazendo "se o dia é zero, pegue o índice zero, se for 1, pegue o índice 1, etc...". Se é assim, então use diretamente o valor como índice:

```
diasemana = dw[diasemana]
```

Ou ainda:

```
diasemana = dw[data.getDay()]
```

E só. A [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/475758/112052) (que foi apagada) disse para usar `for`, mas não precisa, pois ele percorre o array desnecessariamente até encontrar o índice, mas se você já sabe qual é o índice, para que o `for`? **Não** precisa usar `for`, não force o uso de algo que não é necessário. Se o valor que você já tem é o mesmo do índice, pegue ele direto e pronto.

---

Dito isso, dá para simplificar o código, pois existem formatos prontos que você pode usar com [`toLocaleDateString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) e [`toLocaleTimeString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleTimeString):

```js
function carregar(){
    let data = new Date();
    let dw = ["Domingo", "Segunda-Feira", "Terça-Feira", "Quarta-Feira", "Quinta-Feira", "Sexta-Feira", "Sábado"];
    document.getElementById('dias').innerHTML = `${dw[data.getDay()]} ${data.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR")}`;
    document.getElementById('relogio').innerHTML = `${data.toLocaleTimeString("en-US")}`;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { setInterval(carregar, 1000) });
```

```html
<p id="dias"></p>
<p id="relogio"></p>
```

Os *locales* "pt-BR" e "en-US" referem-se respectivamente ao português do Brasil e ao inglês americano, e eles já ajustam os formatos de data e hora de acordo com o que eu entendi que você precisa ("pt-BR" usa o formato de data "dd/mm/aaaa", e "en-US" usa o formato de hora "h:m:s am/pm").

E o segundo parâmetro de [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) é o valor em milissegundos (milésimos de segundo), então coloquei `1000` para atualizar a cada 1 segundo (pois a cada 1 milissegundo, como você fez, me parece "exagero", já que o relógio não vai mostrar as frações de segundo).

Também coloquei ponto-e-vírgula no final das linhas. Pode parecer "frescura", e sei que o JavaScript "aceita" o código sem ponto e vírgula e "funciona", mas isso evita algumas situações bizarras que podem ocorrer se você não usá-los, como [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1169596) e [essa](/q/432960/112052) (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](/q/3341/112052)).

Nem sei se precisava mesmo de uma função só pra isso, mas se quiser muito fazer isso:

```js
function getDiaDaSemana(data) {
    let dw = ["Domingo", "Segunda-Feira", "Terça-Feira", "Quarta-Feira", "Quinta-Feira", "Sexta-Feira", "Sábado"];
    return dw[data.getDay()];
}

function carregar(){
    let data = new Date();
    document.getElementById('dias').innerHTML = `${getDiaDaSemana(data)} ${data.toLocaleDateString("pt-BR")}`;
    document.getElementById('relogio').innerHTML = `${data.toLocaleTimeString("en-US")}`;
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { setInterval(carregar, 1000) });
```

```html
<p id="dias"></p>
<p id="relogio"></p>
```

---

#### Lib externa

Se quiser/puder usar uma lib externa, uma alternativa é o [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). Para ter o nome do dia da semana em português, você vai precisar da [versão com *locales*](https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js):

```js
moment.locale('pt-BR'); // mudar idioma para português

function carregar(){
    let data = moment();
    document.getElementById('dias').innerHTML = data.format('dddd DD/MM/YYYY');
    document.getElementById('relogio').innerHTML = data.format('h:mm:ss A');
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { setInterval(carregar, 1000) });
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>

<p id="dias"></p>
<p id="relogio"></p>
```

Outra alternativa é o [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/):

```js
function carregar(){
    let data = luxon.DateTime.local();
    document.getElementById('dias').innerHTML = data.setLocale('pt-BR').toFormat('EEEE dd/MM/yyyy');
    document.getElementById('relogio').innerHTML = data.toFormat('h:mm:ss a');
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() { setInterval(carregar, 1000) });
```

```html
<script src="https://moment.github.io/luxon/global/luxon.min.js"></script>

<p id="dias"></p>
<p id="relogio"></p>
```

Comment: Não tinha pensado nesta opção:`let dw = ["Domingo", "Segunda-Feira", "Terça-Feira", "Quarta-Feira", "Quinta-Feira", "Sexta-Feira", "Sábado"];
    return dw[data.getDay()];` gostei :)

Comment: `return ["Domingo", "Segunda-Feira", "Terça-Feira", "Quarta-Feira", "Quinta-Feira", "Sexta-Feira", "Sábado"][data.getDay()];`